# ¿por que mi web se ve perfecta en distintos dispositivios pero en ios no?

Tags: html, android, css, ios

eso es, tengo una web, en la cual tiene diferentes background aplicados en css, y en todos los dispositivos se ve con excelente calidad, pero en todos los ios se ve de super mala calidad, y no toma los background-size: cover; por ejemplo.

```
.header{
    margin-top: 8rem;
    height: calc(100vh - 8rem);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: url(../img/header_1.webp);
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

probe con la imagen en distintos formatos, pero ni asi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente campo no tiene soporte en iOS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revisalo aqui:
[MDN background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment)

Comment: El cuadro de compatibilidad está más completo en la [versión en inglés](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

Comment: Genial! lo desactivé y se ve bien ahora. Pero como puedo crear el mismo efecto de fixed ahora sin usar eso?

Answer (score 0):

si lo que deseas es que la imagen se quede estatica en el header o que el header se quede estatico en la parte superior. Puedes utilizar

```
header{
position: sticky;
```

}